# Powerpoint 2016: I'm looking for an efficient way to manage multiple button/image animations, overlapping each other

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have 12 buttons, and each button is specific for one of 12 different images.
When the presentation is running, I'm clicking on the buttons, and the related images show up. Because of issues with layering, and some size differences, I'm making the other 11 images disappear, versus going "behind."

So I currently have 12 copies of this:

- Image 1 appear
- Image 2 disappear
- Image 2 disappear
- .... (each copy changes which one image appears).

This is 144 animations, for this one slide, and I have multiple similar slides. And in the future I might need to add or remove button/images from the slides.

- So this all seems very inefficient, and I'm trying to find a better way.

I tried grouping all of the images, and then "disappearing" the group, and "appearing" one image in the group. But it's not possible to animate part of a group, without animating the whole group.

Any thoughts or opinions on how I can do this better?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll find it simpler and more maintainable to do this for each of the buttons:

Make a copy of the original slide for each of your images; the copy should be identical to the original but have the appropriate image on it.

Make each of these image slides hidden

Make a custom show for each of these slides.

On the main show, make each button a hyperlink to the appropriate single-slide custom show and be sure to checkmark the "Show and return" (or words to that effect) option.

Comment: I was originally using this idea, with copies of the one slide, but then each change to the layout has to be copied each time to each of the copies. This quickly became a maintenance nightmare :(

Comment: Less of a nightmare than managing 144 animations, I'd think ;-)  Apart from that, can't most of the layout come from the slide master the slides are based on?

Comment: In the time since my last comment, I was asked to add three more images to the slides. So now I'm up to 15 images, each with 15 animations. I'm going to try your suggestion of multiple slides. Thank you for your help.